# knitr: ignoring empty lines after upgrade to version 1.20 in python code in latex

Tags: python, latex, knitr

OS: Ubuntu 17.10

After an upgrade of Knitr to version 1.20, all my Python-code in latex didn't work anymore

First I had to install "reticulate".

That did the job but the output was missing all empty lines (very unreadable for my students).

And then again: `echo=-c(1,2)` doesn't work except `echo=F`

This does just concern using as engine Python and not R.

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Ps: another issue: engine Python does not like an # somewhere in the code

Answer (score 0):

The relevant release notes are here: https://github.com/yihui/knitr/releases/tag/v1.18 Specifically:

> [...] if you want the old behavior (new session for each Python code chunk), you can set the chunk option `python.reticulate = FALSE`